# Why do Riemann sums converge?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

I know from calculus that Riemann Integrals are Riemann sums. We use such integrals to calculate areas under curves. But why does adding an infinite amount of small terms give a finite result for non divergent curves? I know the obvious answer would be to just look at the graph of the function and we can see there is a finite area. But I keep thinking of the [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) and how adding an infinite amount of smaller and smaller terms has as a result infinity. How can we be sure the small terms if the Riemann sum also don't add up to infinity?

Comment: You have to check if they diverge or not. Existence of the integral needs to be established first before you calculate it.

Comment: Some infinite sums converge though: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots = 2$.  Precisely,  $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{2^n}=2$, because $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{2^n}=2-\frac{1}{2^N}$ for any fixed number $N$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField but in class we never do that for common functions like polynomials or trigonometric or whatever else there is. We just calculate the antiderivative and plug in the limits of integration. How come we can do that without ever checking like you said?

Comment: Because a calculus class is not the same thing as an analysis class. You prove most of the calculus results in the latter. For instance, you can prove that a bounded function on an interval is Riemann-integrable if it has finitely many discontinuities. This handles most examples you see in a calculus class.

Comment: It sounds like your question is really "Why do some infinite sums converge while others diverge?", not really about integration.

Comment: @akujack many common functions can be integrated especially well-behaved functions like the ones you've described. Historically we started using calculus before we proved any of it worked and in the sciences where rigor is optional this is often enough.

Comment: @MPW you are right, but I only have this question because of integrals, so I figured I ask about them specifically since I did learn about the some series convergence tests but we never performed those when dealing with integrals.

Comment: To me, it isn't clear what the question is. Especially the question in the last sentence, "How can we be sure the small terms if the Riemann sum also don't add up to infinity?" I don't know what this means...

Comment: Riemann integrals are not Riemann sums. They are the limits of Riemann sums, for some complicated definition of "limit."